# How to find the coordinates of the first non-blank cell in a row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I'm trying to find a formula that given a row (1 and 5 in these examples), it will return the coordinates of first non-empty cell in that row. In these examples, the answers should be G1 and J5.

I've tried to use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890557/how-to-find-nearest-non-blank-cell-above-the-current-cell), but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: this seems like it could be an xy-problem.  Would you mind explaining the use case a little? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the cell after the last non-empty cell in the row which I think is what you want.

Should be just a case of using columns instead of rows:

```
=ArrayFormula(address(row()-1,FILTER(column(1:1), COLUMN(1:1)=MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(1:1), NOT(ISBLANK(1:1)))))+1,4))
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "using columns instead of rows"?

Comment: I mean it's basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890557/how-to-find-nearest-non-blank-cell-above-the-current-cell (the question you were referring to) but with a horizontal range instead of vertical.