# Fill in blank cells in ={ARRAYFORMULA()}

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, nested-if

I have a human-friendly sheet with sparse data:

```
PART  | FRUIT
---------------
Alpha | 
      | Apples
      | Pears
Beta  |
      | Lemons
      | Oranges
```

I want to create a second automatically updated machine-friendly sheet, which would have all empty cells in column PART filled:

```
PART  | FRUIT
---------------
Alpha | 
Alpha | Apples
Alpha | Pears
Beta  |
Beta  | Lemons
Beta  | Oranges
```

I am OK to have empty cells in the column FRUIT on the machine-friendly sheet. But ideally I would like such rows removed:

```
PART  | FRUIT
---------------
Alpha | Apples
Alpha | Pears
Beta  | Lemons
Beta  | Oranges
```

If I wanted to use interpolation in the machine-friendly sheet, I would rely on the `MATCH` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891222/6236) or the `FILTER` [paste-anywhere formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891000/6236).

But I really want to avoid updating the machine-friendly sheet when I add, change or remove rows in the original sheet. (I'm OK if I will have to update it if I add new columns to the original sheet.) This means that using manual interpolation is off-limits.

Ideally on the second sheet I would type in a magic `={ARRAYFORMULA()}` or a `=QUERY` of some kind, and then leave it alone.

`={ ARRAYFORMULA(MAGIC(PART)), FRUIT }`

But so far I cannot wrap my head on how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: NB: Any edits improving terminology and visibility of this question in the search are very welcome. I dislike my original title the most, please help me to find a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)))
```

Comment: That works! But is there a way to pack everything in a single formula for extra neatness points?

On my second sheet I have `={ PARTS, FRUITS }` in A1 (I use named ranges referring to the original sheet) and your formula in C2. Can I pack both in A1 somehow?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: This worked for me (I put it in A1 of the machine-readable sheet)

`=FILTER({ ARRAYFORMULA(IF(FRUITS="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(PARTS), IF(PARTS<>"", {ROW(PARTS), PARTS}), 2, 1))), FRUITS}, FRUITS<>"")`