# Fill in blank cells from several columns in ={ARRAYFORMULA()}

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a human-friendly sheet with sparse hierarchical data:

```
SEASON  | FRUIT      | LETTER 
-----------------------------
Winter  |            |
        | Lemons     |
        |            | Delta
Summer  |            |
        |            | Alpha
        |            | Beta
        | Pears      |
        |            | Gamma
```

(Note how `Alpha` and `Beta` don't have a `FRUIT` entry.)

I want to generate a new column, using `ARRAYFORMULA()`, to contain a full "path" to the `LETTER`:

```
SEASON  | FRUIT      | LETTER | PATH
------------------------------------
Winter  |            |        | Winter//
        | Lemons     |        | Winter/Lemons/
        |            | Delta  | Winter/Lemons/Delta
Summer  |            |        | Summer//
        |            | Alpha  | Summer//Alpha
        |            | Beta   | Summer//Beta
        | Pears      |        | Summer/Pears/
        |            | Gamma  | Summer/Pears/Gamma
```

Please help me to understand how to write such `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

---

I'm trying approach, based on answers in [Fill in blank cells in ={ARRAYFORMULA()}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003763/fill-in-blank-cells-in-arrayformula), but I'm stuck at resetting `FRUIT` to empty string for a new `SEASON`. I.e. this naïve implementation would yield `Summer/Lemons/Alpha` instead of `Summer//Alpha`:

```
={ ARRAYFORMULA(
            IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(SEASON), IF(SEASON<>"", { ROW(SEASON), SEASON }), 2, 1), "")
    & "/" & IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(FRUIT),  IF(FRUIT<>"",  { ROW(FRUIT), FRUIT }),   2, 1), "")
    & "/" & LETTER
) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxGHCGQFkjpDrFSwtx3XYuMdk9lsEMCxOgcb-nyzNfA/edit#gid=239549276) created specifically to answer this question.

you will find this formula in cell E1 on a tab called Possible Solution.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A&B:B&C:C),VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},LEN(A:A)),2,1)&"/"&VLOOKUP(ROW(B:B),FILTER({ROW(B:B),B:B},LEN(A:A&B:B)),2,1)&"/"&C:C,))
```

It uses the VLOOKUP(ROW(),FILTER(),[index],TRUE)  technique to append the relevant parts of the path to one another.

Note the portion of the formula in the image which i believe was the crux of the trouble with the strategy you were trying...

[image]